# paste based in the number of elements in the row

Tags: r, string, concatenation

This is my dataframe

```
s <- data.frame(
  x = c("a","b","c"),
  y = c("d","e", NA),
  z = c(NA,"j",NA)
)
```

And I want to concatenate(paste) the values based a condition, I want to paste with comma only the non null values, so the vector I want as result is:

```
a,b,c
d,e
j
```

Maybe it is very simple, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is not GIS or spatial analysis related, this question should be migrated to Stack Overflow but in the meantime.

```
s <- data.frame(
  x = c("a","b","c"),
  y = c("d","e", NA),
  z = c(NA,"j",NA)
)
```

To add the commas as a single vector or by column:

```
paste(sapply(strsplit(as.vector(na.omit(c(s[,1], s[,2], s[,3]))), ""), 
      paste, collapse=":"), collapse=", ")

sapply(as.list(s), function(x) {paste(na.omit(x), collapse=", ")})
```

Comment: Ups! I didn't realized I posted it in the Gis Stack Exchange (I thought I posted it in the stackoverflow), thank you for the warning and for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
library(dplyr)
s %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(toString(na.omit(.)))) %>%
  unlist(., use.names=FALSE)
#[1] "a, b, c" "d, e"    "j"
```

Comment: Nice! dplyr sure is a handy library.